# Python code runs fine in pycharm but gives module error while running in terminal

Tags: python, pycharm

I have my flask project project structure as below which I have deployed to ec2 .

```
myproject 
 --src 
     -- cache  
             --- cache.py
     -- storeservice 
            --- upload.py
           
     -- esService 
            --- es.py
     -- ui
           --- html
           --- static 
    -- main
          --- controller.py
```

In Controller I have the import

```
from storeservice.upload import Upload
```

This works fine on pycharm but when I run via terminal it gives error

command which I use is `python3 controller.py`

```
from storeservice.upload import Upload
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storeservice'
```

Is there a way to execute it without making any code change ?

Comment: Sounds like the execution environments don't match. Ensure you're using the same `python3` executable in each environment by comparing the output of `which python3`. Then take a look at the environment variables, especially PATH, PYTHONPATH, and PYTHONHOME.

Comment: storeservice is normal python code .Python3 --version all works fine .

Comment: Aren't you missing `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Ohh, whoops, I missed the EC2 deployment part, `which python3` isn't applicable here.  Verify the environment variables are correct. PyCharm tries to set values for them based on the project and this probably doesn't happen automatically in EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the folder `/....../myproject/src` to your `PYTHONPATH`, pycharm does that by default, you need to do that manually outside of pycharm.

one of the most portable ways to do that is to create a shell script that modifies your environment with the correct path then executes the python script, you then call that one instead of calling python directly.

Comment: I added it [ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-110 main]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/ec2-user/Downloads/myproject/src but still it gives same error

Comment: @arpitjoshi the error is now because of letter case in your imports, `storeservice` != `storeService` on linux, but you also need the `PYTHONPATH` modification for python to import it after you correct the letter cases.

Comment: no ..that was a typo in question . its storeservice

Comment: @arpitjoshi can you confirm `PYTHONPATH` is modified by printing `sys.path` ?

Comment: It worked .I set the PYTHONPATH to src , after that I was getting another issue with another file but seems it was typo , weirdly it worked on py charm but not in termnial . Now it works in terminal after setting path  .Thank you so much